# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object on update function

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple blog, I can add, delete elements in my blog now I want user to be able to update  tags .

Here is page list tags table in  my phpmyadmin

```
page_lit_tags table

    id  name

    1   test1
    2   test2
```

Here is tags table

[image]

Here is tag controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tag;
use App\PageList;

class TagController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $pages = PageList::all();
        return view('pages.index', compact('tags', 'pages'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($reguest, array('name'=>'required|max:255'));
        $tag = new Tag;
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->save();
        $request->session()->flash('succes', 'Tag was successful created!');
        return redirect()->route('pages.index');
    }
}
```

Here is my page list controller update function

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $pages = PageList::find($id);
        $pages->pagetitle =  $request->get('pagetitle');
        $pages->articlelist = $request->get('articlelist');
        $pages->status = $request->get('status');

        $pages->save();

        $pages->tags()->saveMany([
            new Tag(),
            new Tag(),
        ]);

        return redirect('/pages')->with('success', 'pages updated!');
    }
```

Here is my page inde.blade.php where I am displaying my data

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($pages as $page)

    <tr>
        <td>
            {{$page->id}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$page->pagetitle}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$page->articlelist}}
        </td>
        <td>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$page->id}}">
                {{ __('view tags') }}
            </button>
            <!-- Modal -->

            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$page->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tag List</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead class=" text-primary">
                                    <th>
                                        ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        name
                                    </th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($page->tags as $tag)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $tag->tag->id }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ $tag->tag->name }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

NOTE: I am so new to laravel guys.

When I run my app I get the following problem

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\royalad-dashboard\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)
```

Here is my repo [repository](https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard)

What am I doing wrong in my codes?

Comment: Just `$tag->id`?

Comment: Any time you get "Trying to get property ... of non-object", check for object access (`->`) in the file specified in the error message. Usually, you're calling `->something` on `null` (in this case `$tag->tag` is `null`). Gotta be aware of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

if `$page->tags` gives you a collection of tags, you should simply do `$tag->id` instead of `$tag->tag->id` (and the same for the name attribute)